# Infinite HTTP requests to the back-end when subscribing to an observable

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm adding a feature to an Angular2 site to display the currently logged-in user's name.

I seem to be able to retrieve the information I need from the back-end service.  However, when the front-end code in question is running, requests to the back-end are being sent repeatedly and as fast as possible when only one request is needed.

This infinite loop of requests started when I changed the code to subscribe to an observable.  Without subscribing, the information I was able to retrieve from the front-end service was not usable; it looked like the example below.

```
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":{}}
```

**Component**

```
loggedInUser() {
    this.authService.loggedInUser().subscribe(res => {
      this.currentUser = res;
      return this.currentUser;
   })
}
```

**Front-End Service**

```
loggedInUser() {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    return this.http
       .get('http://localhost:3000/user/current/' + userId)
       .map((response: Response) => {
    const user = response.json();
  return user;
})
```

I learned that this isn't truly an "infinite loop" from reading other posts on Stack Overflow.  I wasn't able to comprehend the solutions in those other posts, however.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to store your information in your localStorage when the user logged In and after simply read it.

```
//In your authService
loggedInUser() {
    return this.http.post(AppSettings.API_URL + 'login', data, this.options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        let username = response.json().data.username;
        if(username){
            localStorage.setItem('username', username);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

//In your login form component
onSubmit() {
     this.authService.loggedInUser(email, ....)
         .subscribe(
             result => {
                 if (result === true) {
                     //It's ok
                 } 
             error => {
                 //error
             }
          )
}
```

If you want to subscribe only one time you could use the take operator.
Don't forget to unsubscribe to your observable when you leave one component or navigate to another one (do this in your ngOnDestroy methods).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without a fiddle but are you calling the component's `loggedInUser` function directly from the template?

In the component, move the subscribe code to the `ngOnInit` hook

```
include { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
class AppComponent implements Oninit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.loggedInUser().subscribe(res => {
      this.currentUser = res;
    });
  }
}
```

Refer to `this.currentUser` in the template

```
<div>Logged in as: {{currentUser}}</div>
```

Best to also `unsubscribe` in `NgOnDestroy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .retry function, so that only sends request for limited number of times.

You can write something like this:

```
loggedInUser() {

    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');

    return this.http

       .get('http://localhost:3000/user/current/' + userId)

       .retry(1)

       .map((response: Response) => {

    const user = response.json();

  return user;

})
```

for this code, if the request fails for the first time, it will try again only  once.

for reference, you can see here - http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html